# IOS Using method from ViewController.m in AppDelegate.m?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, appdelegate

So I have a method in ViewController.m that posts a notification (to notification center) with a push of a button

heres the method from ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)buttonPush:(id)sender {
    //clear NC
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];


    //make mutablearray
    NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray array];


    [list addObject:first];
    [list addObject:second];
    [list addObject:third];



    //post notification
    for (UITextField *thing in list) {
        UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notif.alertBody = thing.text;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notif];
        NSLog(@"looped!");

    }


    }
```

what i want to do is use the above method in the following method (which is in AppDelegate.m):

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: @jsd yes i am, i used a "Touch Down" referencing outlet for the button

Answer (score 1):

You can register to receive a notification in your view controller to be notified when the application will enter the background:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(buttonPush:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: okay, but where would i put this? under 
        - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application  ?

Comment: No. In ViewController.m in the -(void)viewDidLoad method.